# Solution to an ODE 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the solutions to

$$x(t)+\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 e^{t-s} x(s) ds=1.$$

Differential equations are not my field, so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After differentiating the given equation 
$$x(t)+\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 e^{t-s} x(s) ds=1$$
you will get
$$\dot{x}(t)+\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 e^{t-s} x(s) ds=0$$
Now take both equations together to obtain
$$\dot{x}(t)-x(t)=-1$$
This equation has the general solution
$$x(t)=1+Ae^t$$
Finally we have to determine $A$ with the given differential equation:
$$1+Ae^t+\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 e^{t-s}(1+Ae^s)ds=1+\Big(\frac{11}{10}A+\frac{1}{10}\Big(1-\frac{1}{e}\Big)\Big)e^t\stackrel{!}{=}1$$
From this we can conclude, that the term in the brace must be zero, and I got
$$A=\frac{1}{11}\Big(\frac{1}{e}-1\Big)$$
The final solution should now be
$$x(t)=1+\frac{(1-e)}{11}e^{t-1}$$